# Python: Iterating this specific dict (BOTO3)

Tags: python, dictionary, boto3

i'm fairly new with python and BOTO3. I'm getting all the EC2 instances from all my ASG.

The value I need to get is **'InstanceId':**

**This is how i get the dict from AWS**:

```
client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
output = client.describe_auto_scaling_instances()
```

**I've tried with many variations of this without results (key** error):

```
for x in output:
    print(x[0][0])   


for x in output.values():
   print(x)
```

**This is my current response:**

```
{
    'AutoScalingInstances': [{
        'InstanceId': 'i-022d69fc77a62b787',
        'InstanceType': 't3.medium',
        'AutoScalingGroupName': 'sarasa',
        'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1c',
        'LifecycleState': 'InService',
        'HealthStatus': 'HEALTHY',
        'LaunchConfigurationName': 'sarasa',
        'ProtectedFromScaleIn': False
    }, {
        'InstanceId': 'i-055b3d5cefec5c3f3',
        'InstanceType': 't3.small',
        'AutoScalingGroupName': 'pepe',
        'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a',
        'LifecycleState': 'InService',
        'HealthStatus': 'HEALTHY',
        'LaunchConfigurationName': 'pepe',
        'ProtectedFromScaleIn': False
    }],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': '6333c5-e9c7-47e7-9060-asdadadad',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': '6333c5-e9c7-47e7-9060-asdadadad',
            'content-type': 'text/xml',
            'content-length': '4399',
            'vary': 'accept-encoding',
            'date': 'Tue, 07 Jun 2022 13:00:12 GMT'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what have you tried, but you could do the following (and adjust according to what you need)

```
d = {
    'AutoScalingInstances': [{
        'InstanceId': 'i-022d69fc77a62b787',
        'InstanceType': 't3.medium',
        'AutoScalingGroupName': 'sarasa',
        'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1c',
        'LifecycleState': 'InService',
        'HealthStatus': 'HEALTHY',
        'LaunchConfigurationName': 'sarasa',
        'ProtectedFromScaleIn': False
    }, {
        'InstanceId': 'i-055b3d5cefec5c3f3',
        'InstanceType': 't3.small',
        'AutoScalingGroupName': 'pepe',
        'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a',
        'LifecycleState': 'InService',
        'HealthStatus': 'HEALTHY',
        'LaunchConfigurationName': 'pepe',
        'ProtectedFromScaleIn': False
    }],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': '6333c5-e9c7-47e7-9060-asdadadad',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'x-amzn-requestid': '6333c5-e9c7-47e7-9060-asdadadad',
            'content-type': 'text/xml',
            'content-length': '4399',
            'vary': 'accept-encoding',
            'date': 'Tue, 07 Jun 2022 13:00:12 GMT'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    }
}
for k in d.keys():
    for elem in d[k]:
        if s in elem:
            print(elem[s])
```

it will return:

```
i-022d69fc77a62b787
i-055b3d5cefec5c3f3
```